# Detecting console input in developer tools

Tags: javascript, input, console

I've been working with JavaScript for a while now, and I was wondering how I would detect and use console input, and assign said input to variables. I've been using prompts to get user input, but It's inefficient and stops the rest of the program, and I was looking for a better alternative when I thought about this possibility.

Comment: Which console, the node.js command line repl? Or the browser devtools console? In the latter case, no you cannot access that from the website.

Comment: Use input fields in the page. Of course that will require you to change your code to deal with asynchrony, but anything that doesn't use `prompt`s will.

Comment: Why not using an `input` element in a normal form?

Comment: I'm using command line repl.

Comment: @Superdog What "prompt" did you use there? Can you show us your code?

Comment: assuming that I used a 
var var1 = prompt("test")
console.log("Problem")
if(var1 == test){alert("yes")}

The console.log wouldn't print until all alerts would finish.

Comment: as @NickHTTPS, suggested, you should use normal html `input` tags. Else please explain your use case, why do you want to use the `prompt`?

Comment: @NickHTTPS How would I use input in the first place?

Comment: I don't want to use prompt, I want to find an alternative by using console input, and the code that I used was an example that would stop all console.logs until all prompts/alerts have been read/responded to.

Comment: @Superdog So, not the command line REPL if you use `prompt` and `alert`.

Comment: My bad! I meant the Dev Tools console! I was thinking using something to similar to pythons input function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I'd suggest something like this:

```
<form action="/process-form" method="post" id="myForm">
  <label for="myVar">What variable do you want to set?</label>
  <input name="myVar" id="myVar" value="">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Process that with JS

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(event.target);
  // Assign the user input to the global scope so you can do whatever you want
  window.myVar = formData.get('myVar');
});
```

Comment: `new FormData(event.target).get('myVar')` - interesting. `document.getElementById('myVar').value` might be simpler :-)

Comment: "*Assign the user input to the global scope so you can do whatever you want*" - no, don't do that. You don't know when to do what. You will need to do the things that you want to do within the submit callback. You should call a function, and pass the user input as an argument.

Comment: I partially disagree. Globals are not bad things. They can turn into though! I was just showing how you can get a value from an user input not showing how to design software. Depends on the use case globals are ok to use with cautions. Yours is a good advice in the majority of the cases :)